# I can't post session & post variable in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi guys I have below code for creating a simple php private message I have below send form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="send.php">
<label>To</label>
<select name="To" class="form-control">
<option value="user">user</option>
<option value="user1">user1</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="From" value="<?php $_SESSION['user'];?>">
<label>Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject">
<label>Message</label>
<textarea class="form-control" cols="40" name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="Date" value="<?php date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?>">
<button type="submit" name="Send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button></form>
```

and my php code is as below:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['Send'])){
    $To = $_POST['To'];
    $From = $_POST['From'];
    $Sub = $_POST['Subject'];
    $Mess = $_POST['Message'];
    $Date = $_POST['Date'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO pm from, to, sub, mess, date VALUES '$From', '$To', '$Sub', '$Mess', '$Date'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if($result == true){
$sent = "Message sent Successfully";
header("Location: Home.php?message=$sent");
}
else{
$ntsent = "Message not sent Successfully";
header("Location: Home.php?message=$ntsent");
}
mysqli_close($con); 
}
?>
```

It always says message not sent successfully message can you please guess what is wrong?

Comment: Your query failed because you had an obvious syntax error. But you don't know that because you don't check for errors.

Comment: any sample query related to this?

Comment: `mysqli_error()` will tell you the error in your SQL syntax.  Though there could be any number of problems with the SQL query, since it's wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: rest of code seems okay?

Comment: even though it shows no errors just says not sent message

Comment: `<?php $_SESSION['user'];?>` does nothing, you need to `echo`

Comment: Additionally columns and values need to be encapsulated in parenthesis and `from` is a reserved term. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: I suggest you read up (and maybe take a tutorial) on 1) error handling in PHP / MySQLi, 2) basic SQL syntax, 3) SQL injection and parameterised queries. It would help you avoid low-level problems like this

Comment: Hi, the query is worked out after I changed reserved keywords but I can't still post from user as $_session['user']; and date. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your INSERT query is incomplete. Try this out

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (pm, from, to, sub, mess, date) VALUES ('$From', '$To', '$Sub', '$Mess', '$Date'");
```